# empty queue in google cloud run with plumber R api

Tags: google-cloud-run, plumber

Is it possible to empty the queue of tasks on google cloud run where I run a plumber API? I will get a lot of pushes in a batch, but I just want to run the script once. So the best solution would be to delete the post requests waiting in the queue at the end of the calculation.

I could not find a good solution yet. Do you have any tips or tricks? Any help is appreciated.

Asked a similar question on Rstudio community [HERE](https://community.rstudio.com/t/empty-concurrency-queue-of-post-requests-on-plumber-api-running-on-gcr/79723)

Comment: Can you add more details about how you're running Plumber on Cloud Run?

Comment: I am running a docker container based on rocker/tidyverse. The container calls the route on entrypoint, and runs the API. The question has been answered on rstudio community sorry for not updating this. If you have different suggestions to solve it I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

The question is answered on [Rstudio community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/empty-queue-of-post-requests-on-plumber-api-running-on-gcr/79723/2?u=martonbalazskovacs).